# How to change FontFamily when user choose specific item in ComboBox (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

[image]

```
<ComboBox x:Name="theComboBox">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Use Default Font"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Static onts.SystemFontFamilies}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock Text="Text in selected font" FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=theComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

I binded fontfamily of the textblock to choosed font in the combobox. It works correctly. But I want when user click **"use default font"**, fontfamily of textblock changes to this:

```
FontFamily={StaticResource Great} //Great.ttf is an embedded font in my project
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly do you want to happen when user selects `use default font`, and what's the problem you have with this code?

Comment: @Sach I've updated question. When user selects "use default font", fontfamily of textblock should changes to specific font. in here great.ttf which is my default font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the SelectionChanged event of the combobox to call a method, where you check, if the selected item is the one you want (yourItem), you set the textblock's FontFamily to the one you want (YourFont).

```
<ComboBox x:Name="theComboBox" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Use Default Font"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Static onts.SystemFontFamilies}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock x:Name="myTextblock" Text="Text in selected font" FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=theComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

And,

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (theComboBox.SelectedItem = yourItem)
    {
        myTextBlock.FontFamily = YourFont;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `FallbackValue` property of the binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="Text in selected font" FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=theComboBox, 
                                 Path=SelectedItem, FallbackValue={StaticResource Great}}" />
```

Comment: @kokabi: Did you try with an installed font family like `FallbackValue='Arial'`? Works just fine for me.